# How-to derive conical region in an arbitrary geometry?

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

**Description**

I have been working with derived geometric regions and ran into a problem when deriving `RegionIntersection` of a `Cone` with respect to a bounding `Cuboid`

**Example 1**

```
Module[
 {
  R1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}],
  R2 = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, 3]
  },
 Show[{
   Graphics3D[{Opacity @ 0.05, R2}],
   RegionPlot3D[R1, PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity @ 0.3]],
   RegionPlot3D[RegionIntersection[R2, R1]]
   },
  Boxed -> False]
 ]
```

**Output 1**

[image: example no. 1]

**Example 2**

```
Module[
 {
  R1 = Fold[RegionDifference, 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}], {Cylinder[{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 5}}, 
      1], Cylinder[{{3, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 5}}, 1]}],
  R2 = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, 3]
  },
 Show[{
   Graphics3D @ {Opacity @ 0.05, Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, 3]},
   RegionPlot3D[R1, PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity @ 0.3]],
   RegionPlot3D[RegionIntersection[R1, R2]]
   },
  Boxed -> False]
 ]
```

**Output 2**

[image: example 2]

**EDIT1 (Example of somewhat desired output using alternative solid geometry)**

**Code**

```
Module[
 {
  module  = Fold[RegionDifference, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}], {Cylinder[{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 5}}, 1], Cylinder[{{3, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 5}}, 1]}],
  tetra = Tetrahedron[{{0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}]
  },
 Show[{
   RegionPlot3D[module, PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity @ 0.3]],
   RegionPlot3D @ RegionIntersection[module, tetra]
   }]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: alternative geometry]

In the above examples, on both outputs I was expecting a filled `Cone` region with its base lining-up against the bounding `Cuboid`. However, the output left me puzzled and I was hoping someone could explain me if I am missing something and how I could achieve the desired output?

Comment: RegionIntersection is just not good at 3D.... It will not work if the regions are MeshRegions, it does work for some special geometric regions but in this case it explicitly gives the wrong answer.  You can see a related, but different problem, if you run this on your first example:  `{Show[Graphics3D /@ {R1, R2}]
 , RegionPlot3D[{R1, R2}]}`

Comment: @Jasonisnolongerapostdoc is there a known reason for this? How could I formulate a workaround to this problem? I would be interested to use conical regions with more complex geometric configurations :s

Comment: I don't know why it won't work in this case, I've been hoping for a `RegionIntersection` for 3D `MeshRegions` for a while now.  In terms of a workaround - you want to show the whole cone with an opacity of 0.05 like above, but with the portion of the cone inside the cube in the normal orange (or some other style specified later)?  And you'd like to be able to see inside the orange cone section? That last bit is tricky, haven't got it yet

Comment: I have also tried a few ways around but can't seem to get it to work. Ideally, I would like this `Cone` to include only the parts which are present in `R1` as shown in the example no. 2. `R1` may change (imagine it to be some sort of a room with obstacles). I would be interested in a generic solution. Given this region is derived, I will be using it in `RandomPoint` to generate an arbitrary no. of points.

Comment: The best I could think of would be to use some function that takes `RegionFunction` as an option to draw the cone.  This means you take the parametric equations for a cone `{Cos[t] z, Sin[t] z, z}`, rotate and translate them to be the cone you are looking for, and then use `ParametricPlot3D` with the option `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, {x, y, z} \[Element] R1]`.  I know it's a lot of work, so maybe someone else can come up with a better method.

Comment: Thanks @Jasonisnolongerapostdoc, I appreciate your time and will take on your advise! I have tried using `Tetrahedron` instead of a `Cone` and get a result similar to what I have expected with a `Cone`. Will continue to work on a `Cone`

Comment: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, 3], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}]], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.2}]` gives a usable approximation.

Comment: @J.M. Hi, sorry I couldn't get it to work. Mathematica throws an error saying `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` was unable to discretize the region :s

Comment: Huh... what version are you on? It works in 10.4.1 ...

Comment: I am running 10.3.1 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: @J.M. - I can confirm this doesn't work on 10.3.1 but it [does work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xivqM.png) on later versions.  I'm not sure if OP wants the cone to be hollow or not, allowing you to see into it from the big end.  It doesn't seem to work when the R1 region is more complicated though, as in the second example

Comment: @JasonB I will edit question shortly to visualize an example with `Tetrahedron` which sort of reflects what I would like to see but with a `Cone`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the tetrahedra solution give a better result, you need to increase the PlotPoints, like this:

```
Module[
  {
    module = Fold[
      RegionDifference,
      Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}],
      {
        Cylinder[{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 5}}, 1],
        Cylinder[{{3, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 5}}, 1]
      }
    ],
    tetra = Tetrahedron[{{0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}]
  },
  Show[
    {
      RegionPlot3D[
        module, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity@0.3]
      ], 
      RegionPlot3D[
        RegionIntersection[module, tetra], 
        PlotPoints -> 100, 
        Mesh -> All
      ]
    },
    ImageSize -> Medium
  ]
]
```

[image: Tetrahedron with 100 PlotPoints]

And to get a good RegionPlot of the original code, you should discretize the region in the RegionPlot3D:

```
Module[
 {
   R1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}],
   R2 = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, 3]
  },
  Show[
    {
      Graphics3D[{Opacity@0.05, R2}],
      RegionPlot3D[R1, PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity@0.3]],
      RegionPlot3D[
        DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[R2, R1], PrecisionGoal -> 10]
      ]
    },
    Boxed -> False
  ]
]
```

[image: Discretized RegionIntersection]

Note: the PrecisionGoal smooths the surface of the RegionIntersection object

I hope this helps.  You may find many calculations struggle on the direct symbolic solution of 3D region intersections, in those cases try discretizing the region first (you can increase different precision options to DiscretizeRegion for better results).

Nia Knibbs Vaughan
Wolfram Research Technical Consultant

Comment: What version of Mathematica did you use to produce the cone intersection?

Comment: My Mathematica version is 11.0.1.0 (and am using Windows 10).

Comment: The reason why I am asking is because the cone doesn't seem to discretize on version 10.3 :s It works with tetrahedron though

Comment: Interesting.  DiscretizeRegion has not been updated between the versions (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) for more info - bottom of the page has update information) so there should be no difference.  It is possible that an option needs to be modified, could you post/describe the issue you are having with the cone?

Comment: I did refer to the documentation, I think I might be missing something obvious... but here is the [screenshot](https://goo.gl/fILBpU)

Comment: That is very odd, have you tried it in a completely clean session?  I can't see any obvious errors with your code.  Some things that I would try:

 - do it in 2D (so use Disk and Rectangle)

 - try just doing the RegionIntersection, then just the DiscretizeRegion
 - Try using Trace on the computation to see what is happening step by step