# Issue with discretizing two arbitrary regions

Tags: graphics, regions, discretization

### Description

This is in relation to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118991/how-to-derive-conical-region-in-an-arbitrary-geometry) question. I am trying to derive this conical figure yet I seem to get an error with this code. I would be happy if someone could point out how to solve this problem

### Code

```
Module[
 {
  R1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}],
  R2 = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, 3]
  },
 Show[{
   Graphics3D[{Opacity@0.05, R2}], 
   RegionPlot3D[R1, PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity@0.3]],
   RegionPlot3D[
    DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[R2, R1], PrecisionGoal -> 10]
    ]
   },
  Boxed -> False]
 ]
```

### Error

> Skeleton is not a graphics directive
>   Skeleton is not Graphics3D primitive or directive
>   `DiscretizeRegion` was unable to discretize the
>   region `RegionIntersection`

### System

Windows 10 x 64
Mathematica 10.3

Comment: Works in 10.4 and 11.0 (I confirm it doesn't in 10.3)

Comment: Is there a workaround to this problem? It seems like the problem lays with `DiscretizeRegion` but it hasn't been updated since v10.2

Comment: I don't know. "Updated in 10.2" means almost nothing.  I think it refers to the API, not the implementation, and it's missing for several symbols even when the API did change ...  11.0 is clearly better at discretizing regions than 10.2 was.

Comment: [The conical output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNrMu.jpg) This is an output from my MacBook Pro . I looks like you have something else unintentionally pasted in your notebook. Open a new project and paste exactly the code used here. Can you also attached your notebooks here? Add a `SystemInformation[]`

Comment: What version of Mathematica you run it on?

Comment: 11.0.1.0  for Mac OS 10

Comment: thank you for your reply, we've established it works on versions 10.4 and 11.0. It doesn't work on version 10.3 which I am currently using :)

Comment: This answer might be better as a comment, especially since an earlier answer also provided the image.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56278)

Comment: @e.doroskevic Are you using a Mac?  The new Chang compiler will not work on Mathematica 10.3 and this will cause you graphic not to render

Comment: Jose please refer to the OP, I have included this information

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand what the issue is and only post this in case it facilitates:

```
Module[{r1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}], 
  r2 = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}, 3]},
 i = DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[r1, r2]];
 Show[
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], White, r1, Opacity[0.1], LightBlue, r2}],
  RegionPlot3D[i, PlotPoints -> 50],
  Boxed -> False, Background -> Black
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Improvements to discretization may be suggested by others.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work in version v10.3. Up-vote for the effort! :P

Comment: @e.doroskevic ok. I hope others can be helpful. Good luck:)